# Pass String and Integer from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, string, arraylist, integer, fragment

I have problem with my app, can you give me solution for this? *I need to send string and integer* (sName and sPrice) from **MainActivity** into **CartFragment**, and then *I will populate the string and integer into listview*. The coding like this :

**MainActivity.java**

```
ArrayList<String> sName = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> sPrice = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.shop_list);

    ProductView();

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, sName, sPrice);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
        if(position == 0) {
             ?
        }
        if(position == 1) {
             ?

        }
        if(position == 2) {
             ?

        }
        if(position == 3) {
             ?
        }
        if(position == 4) {
             ?
        }
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ditambahkan ke keranjang", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
}

private void ProductView() {
    sName.add("Cabai");
    sPrice.add(5000);
    sName.add("Tomat");
    sPrice.add(3000);
    sName.add("Terong");
    sPrice.add(6000);
    sName.add("Wortel");
    sPrice.add(5000);
    sName.add("Kecambah");
    sPrice.add(4000);
}
```

and this is **CartFragment.java**

```
ArrayList<String> cart_name = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> cart_price = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    ?????????????????????????????????????

    ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.cart_list);

    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), cart_name, cart_price);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, v, position, id) ->
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), cart_name.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    return view;
}
```

I need the solution for this, because I was try it with bundle and nothing happen. **Thanks for your help**.

Comment: Do you want to pass when creating the fragment? Or any other time?

Comment: You tried `cartFragment.setArguments(bundle);` and it didn't work?

Comment: @AnantaRaha I want to pass when creating fragment, I initiate like this, when clicking on the position, the string is sending and passing to fragment and .add to ArrayList

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS it did not working, I was try harder to use bundle

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You possibly want to pass arraylist into the fragment when creating, so that you can use them in your fragment. You should use [`Bundle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle). Following will work properly:

**CartFragment.java**

```
ArrayList<String> cart_name = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> cart_price = new ArrayList<>();

/* Put a factory method for convenience */
public static CartFragment newInstance(ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> prices) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArrayList("names", names);
    args.putIntegerArrayList("prices", prices);
    CartFragment fragment = new CartFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /* Retrieve your data, you can also retrieve inside onCreate() method */
    cart_name = getArguments("names").getStringArrayList();
    cart_price = getArguments("prices").getIntegerArrayList();

    ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.cart_list);
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), cart_name, cart_price);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, v, position, id) ->
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), cart_name.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    return view;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
// Do not write: CartFragment fragment = new CartFragment();
/* Create your fragment with your arguments */
CartFragment fragment = CartFragment.newInstance(sName, sPrice);

...
```

Before passing your arguments, also make sure your `sName` and `sPrice` are not empty list.